# Azure search service index notification on exceeding number of fields

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Is there any provision in azure search service to add trigger or provide notification on exceeding number of fields?

Because I am using "Basic" tier and it allows 100 fields and my application generates more than 100 fields. I am not sure but I believe after exceeding something around 900- 1000 fields it deleted my index automatically.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt more fields than permitted by the service tier quota, your `Create Index` or `Update Index` API calls will fail with the corresponding error message. Under no circumstances will Azure Search ever delete your index automatically.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.I found the reason for this. In our application we have written logic to update Index i.e. first delete and then create. So in that case it deletes the index but when it is trying to create index it gives bad request and creation fails, I was thinking it deleted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

After an RnD I have found that there is no any provision to add trigger, we need to upgrade from **"Basic"** tier to **"Standard"** or more.